# Looping through data and style into specific lists? Ruby/ERB

Tags: html, css, ruby

I am trying to achieve this kind of list: http://alistapart.com/d/multicolumnlists/example2.html

This is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <ol>
  <% CraigslistZipCode.select("distinct region, fee").each do |record| %>
   <li><%= record.region %> <%= record.fee %></li>
  <% end %>
 </ol>
</div>
```

I have to loop through the records, and I don't know how that allows any room to style the data into the three column lists I am seeking. I am trying to avoid the data from running on for an extremely long scroll, and instead pop the data up to another list after a certain number.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want each column to have at most 5 entries.

```
max_rows = 5

items = (1..13).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

# Pad array so that size is divisible by max_rows
items.fill(nil, items.size, (max_rows - items.size) % max_rows)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, nil, nil]

# Slice into groups of max_rows and transpose
items.each_slice(max_rows).to_a.transpose
# => [[1,  6,  11],
#     [2,  7,  12],
#     [3,  8,  13],
#     [4,  9, nil],
#     [5, 10, nil]]
```

You now have an array of rows suitable for columnised output, just remember to check for empty items added by padding.

The reason you need to pad with empty values is that [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) requires all entries to be of equal length.

Comment: The transpose is not required as the layout is done in columns (wrapper div) and then the rows (li tags). Your solution would be a better fit for a table layout where the content is added row-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each_slice` to build groups of items. You will need to make sure that each group holds enough items that all items can be displayed in three columns.

```
<%
records = CraigslistZipCode.select("distinct region, fee")
group_size = (records.count / 3.0).ceil
%>
<% records.each_slice(group_size) do |group| %>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ol>
      <% group.each do |zip_code| %>
        <li><%= record.region %> <%= record.fee %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
  </div>
<% end %>
```